# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Round' with these attrs. Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:<no registered kernels>

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, style-transfer

I am getting error while trying to apply tensorflow model(.pb) in android, The model is loaded sucessfully but after that getting this error.I have trained tensorflow model on CPU.Any help will be appreciated.

> No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Round' with these attrs. Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: That's strange... Is this a custom build of the Android TF runtime? It seems as if kernels had not been compiled into the library (round for floats on CPU is pretty basic and should be available in any configuration).

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for a reply. Yes, round for floats should be available on CPU but don't know why it's not working, Android TF is working fine if I use pretrained models but not working with my model.